# The best software for users internet usage

Tags: monitoring, internet, port, usage, mirroring

We are a small business using a Vigor 2820 as the internet router, and we'd like to install a software that could report any internet usage from our users.

I already tried the "official" software made by Draytek called "SmartMonitor", but is reliability is a real issue as it doesn't seem to keep capturing packets after working 3 to 6hours (randomly), whereas Wireshark keeps capturing packets after that amount of time. As I'm really fed up with this tool, I'm looking for other solutions but I still want the same features: users statistics, websites ranking, users traffic, ...

I already enabled the port mirroring feature, so it would be perfect if you could suggest me a port mirroring-based software (ideally freeware). I thought I had found the good one with Etherscout, but it just doesn't launch.
I am even open to a tool that would "just" make some reports based on Wireshark captured files (*.pcap).

Thank you for any of your suggestion,
Nicolas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally choose the PRTG program (the free version with 10 sensors) and everything seems to work fine.
Maybe if our needs and our network increase I would rather be looking for a proxy server solution as Chopper3 suggested, but for now it's enough for us.

Answer (score 0):

Put a dedicated proxy/cache/firewall between your users and your router - you'll see performance and security benefits plus be able to log all traffic. Any old PC running linux should do if you have one lying around.

Comment: Hi, I don't want to add a proxy and change every user's configuration. We are happy with the current network configuration, we just want to know more about users internet usage, that's why the port mirroring and a PC plugged directly into the router still seems a good solution to me. The proxy is a good solution, you're right but I'm not looking for that solution, thanks.

Comment: Why would you have to change the user's config, just give the proxy the IP address of your default gateway, change the router's interface IP and set that as the proxy's DG.

Comment: Yeah I know, it was exactly what I wanted to say by "user's config". But in this case, what software would you use to display (graphically) the results? Maybe if there's a really great graphic report tool I would look for your solution. Thanks.

Comment: MS Proxy Server or MS ISA will do this, still looking for free linux options though, back in a bit.

Comment: Thanks for seeking. I am more looking for a free soft to do that (windows or linux). Cheers.

Comment: So, you didn't find anything I guess ? =/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much detail you want you can use [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/news.php) hooked up to the mirror port.  The Mirror port would mirror the port that connects to the gateway of course.  Also keep in mind Mirror ports might not always be stable on switches, I have seen them bork 3coms before.

This would be more suited for things like getting an overview of who might me sucking up your bandwidth that it would be for spying on all of a users activity (Which is something I personally am against).

Comment: Hi, I need to see for example a top of visited websites, and the repartition between the users, I'm not auiet sure ntop does that for what I've seen. The question here is not to know if we are against that idea or not, I just have to do it; I never said it was the way I think ;)